# Wiring up text parts

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I'm currently trying to wireup text parts to describe some thing like Unix file permissions or the output of an

```
ls -al
```

But I have no clue how I can create something like this:

[image]

I was thinking about using `\path` or `\node` from Ti*k*Z

But I didn`t get it to work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blue]
\node (a) at (0,0) {-};
\node (b) at (1,0) {rwx};
\node (c) at (2,0) {rw-};
\node (d) at (3,0) {r-\--};
\draw (a.south west)--(a.south east);
\draw (b.south west)--(b.south east);
\draw (c.south west)--(c.south east);
\draw (d.south west)--(d.south east);
\draw (d.south)--($(d.south)+(0,-1)$)--($(d.south)+(1,-1)$) node[right,align=left,font=\scriptsize\sffamily] {Read, write and execute\\permissions for all other users};
\draw (c.south)--($(c.south)+(0,-2)$)--($(c.south)+(2,-2)$) node[right,align=left,font=\scriptsize\sffamily] {Read, write and execute permissions for\\members of the group owning the file};
\draw (b.south)--($(b.south)+(0,-3)$)--($(b.south)+(3,-3)$) node[right,align=left,font=\scriptsize\sffamily] {Read, write and execute permissions\\for the owner of the file};
\draw (a.south)--($(a.south)+(0,-4)$)--($(a.south)+(4,-4)$) node[right,align=left,font=\scriptsize\sffamily] {File type: ``---'' means a file.\\``d'' means a directory};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I basically stole JouleV's answer and revised it to use relative positioning and pack the nodes closer together.  Specifically, the gap between the text of two adjacent nodes is 2 times `inner sep`.  Unfortunately, `inner sep` is also added to the lines under the text, so there I had to reduce `inner xsep` and increase the separation using `[right=4pt]`.

BTW, the default for `inner sep` is 0.333em.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blue]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=2pt}]
  \node (a) {-};
  \node[right=4pt] (b) at (a.east) {rwx};
  \node[right=4pt] (c) at (b.east) {rw-};
  \node[right=4pt] (d) at (c.east) {r-\--};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={below right, align=left, font=\scriptsize\sffamily}]
  \node (e) at (d.south east) {Read, write and execute\\permissions for all other users};
  \node (f) at (e.south west) {Read, write and execute permissions for\\members of the group owning the file};
  \node (g) at (f.south west) {Read, write and execute permissions\\for the owner of the file};
  \node (h) at (g.south west) {File type: ``---'' means a file.\\``d'' means a directory};
\end{scope}
\draw (a.south west)--(a.south east)
  (b.south west)--(b.south east)
  (c.south west)--(c.south east)
  (d.south west)--(d.south east)
  (a.south) |- (h.west)
  (b.south) |- (g.west)
  (c.south) |- (f.west)
  (d.south) |- (e.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]